# How can I render the contents of an array of arrays in React?

Tags: reactjs, render

I am really surprised I even have to ask this question but I am completely stumped. In **Angular** I use nested `*ngFor` but in **React** I can't figure out how to render a 2d array that's fetched from an API. I have no problem with rendering a flat array. (example below)

The 2D array is to generate separate rows of icons. Perhaps I could use a filter with the `row` property on each of the icon objects; I would really like to know how to traverse a 2D array.

*snipets*
**React** works with flat array

```
{this.state.icons.map((icon) => (
  <li className="icons">
    {icon.type === 'icon' && (
      <a href={icon.targetUri} target="_blank">
          <img
            className="large-icon"
            src={icon.image} />
      </a>
    )}
  </li>
))}
```

**Angular 9**

```
 <div class="col-12">
      <ul       
        runInsideAngular="false"
        *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index;">
        <li 
          class="icons"
          *ngFor="let icon of row"
...
```

[image]

Comment: I pretty sure you can just nest `map()` calls.

Comment: I was pretty sure too but I couldn't get it to render. I'll try again in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply nest `.map()` calls

Here is a working example :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t2hrra

```
const arrOfArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {arrOfArray.map(arr => {
        return arr.map(a => {
          return <p>{a}</p>
        })
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your snippet proved to me I am doing it the correct way with nested `map`. There's something wrong in my data although it looks perfectly fine when inspected with chrome components extension. BTW the link isn't working correctly.

Comment: I hardcoded an example of my data and it works perfectly with nested map. So something is failing when I fetch the data, I now think the two dimensional array is not ready by the time the render is fired.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought I was going mad. I'm an Angular dev testing out React and I like what I see so far. I just need to figure out why my data is bad in the app but hardcoded it's fine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nested-map-2d-array?file=src/App.js